# sparklyr + rsparkling: Error while connecting to a cluster

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparklyr, sparkling-water

For some time I'm using `sparklyr` package to connect to companys Hadoop cluster using the code:

```
library(sparklyr)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark/")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre")

system('kinit -k -t user.keytab user@xyz')

sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn",
                config = list(
                  default = list(
                    spark.submit.deployMode= "client",
                    spark.yarn.keytab= "user.keytab",
                    spark.yarn.principal= "user@xyz",
                    spark.executor.instances= 20, 
                    spark.executor.memory= "4G",
                    spark.executor.cores= 4,
                    spark.driver.memory= "8G")))
```

and everything works fine, but when I'm trying to add `rsparkling` package using similar code:

```
library(h2o)
library(rsparkling)
library(sparklyr)

options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = '2.0')

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark/")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre")

system('kinit -k -t user.keytab user@xyz')

sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn",
                config = list(
                  default = list(
                    spark.submit.deployMode= "client",
                    spark.yarn.keytab= "user.keytab",
                    spark.yarn.principal= "user@xyz",
                    spark.executor.instances= 20, 
                    spark.executor.memory= "4G",
                    spark.executor.cores= 4,
                    spark.driver.memory= "8G")))
```

I'm getting error:

> Error in force(code) :
>   Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (9819): Sparklyr gateway did not respond
>   while retrieving ports information after 60 seconds Path:
>   /opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit Parameters: --class,
>   sparklyr.Backend, --packages,
>   'ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.11:2.0','ai.h2o:sparkling-water-ml_2.11:2.0','ai.h2o:sparkling-water-repl_2.11:2.0',
>   '/usr/lib64/R/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.0-2.11.jar', 8880, 9819
>
> ---- Output Log ----
>   Ivy Default Cache set to: /opt/users/user/.ivy2/cache The jars for the packages stored in:
>   /opt/users/user/.ivy2/jars :: loading settings :: url =
>   jar:file:/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
>   ai.h2o#sparkling-water-core_2.11 added as a dependency
>   ai.h2o#sparkling-water-ml_2.11 added as a dependency
>   ai.h2o#sparkling-water-repl_2.11 added as a dependency :: resolving
>   dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
>       confs: [default]
>
> ---- Error Log ----
>   In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if (nchar(config[[e]]) == 0) found <- FALSE :   the condition has length
>   1 and only the first element will be used 2: In if (nchar(config[[e]]) == 0) found <- FALSE :   the condition has length
>   1 and only the first element will be used

I'm new to `spark` and `clusters` and not really sure what to do now. Any help will be very appreciated. My first thought were missing `jar` files for `sparkling water` on the `cluster` side, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use exact version number of Sparkling Water:

`options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = '2.0.5')`

Or you can download binary version of Sparkling Version directly from http://h2o.ai/download, unzip it and replace statement above by:

`options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.location = "/tmp/sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.0.99999-SNAPSHOT-all.jar")`